# Strange Boxed Output

Tags: c

I am population an integer stack implemented through an array with integer values, but I am getting a strange boxed output of 4 numbers.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zWUm.png
The values being inputted are correct, but it shows up in the bottom right corner of the box instead.

I do not believe this to be an issue with the output itself, but the input into the array.

```
void pushValStack (int stack[], int *top, int val) {
    *top + = 1;
    stack[*top] = val;
}

// In Main Function
for (i=1; i<argcl; i++) {
    char *token = argv[i];
...
int value;
sscanf(token, "%d", &value);
pushValStack(valStack, &valCount, value);
printf("Count %d: %c \n", valCount, valStack[valCount]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the value as a character with `%c`, try using `%d`.

Those boxes are one way to represent unprintable characters.

Answer (score 1):

There are few issue that worth fixing:

1. Code read integer ('sscanf ... %d'), but print the values as characters ('printf ... %c'). So the '2' and '4' tokens are converted into the numbers 2, 4, and when displayed as characters. Since there is no graphic characters for 2, 4 (in standard charset), they are displayed as boxed 0002 and 0004. Considering changing printf to use '%d'
2. There is no check on the 'sscanf' call. Since many tokens are not numeric (e.g., '['), they will fail to parse, and value will not be assigned (probably keeping previous value). Consider explicit handling of failed sscanf.
3. From the output looks like there is some additional code that handles non-numeric values - which will display tokens like '[' and '+'. Consider adding a tag to the stack that will allow you to tell the type of each entry: symbol or value.